# Gurobi/python: writing the ''for'' statement for indexing in constraints

Tags: python, indexing, constraints, gurobi

I have the next constraint:

[image: the constraint]

My question is regard to the indexing at the right-hand side;
is it correct to say :

`for r in R for i in N if i not in Cr`
or how should I write it, please?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I wrote the whole constraint, however, I am confused about writing the indexing:
for r in R for N not in Cr. 

I am thinking of creating a different set for N/Cr and call it , for example M

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code you wrote and the error message you received. Also please specify the index sets you are using.

Comment: @mattmilten I wrote the code for this constraint, but what I am asking about is the right way of saying, i for i in (a set N but not in a set Cr). as per the syntax  I wrote for the iteration in my question, I have no error right now.

Answer (score 1):

To check whether the generated model is correct, you should write it out as [LP file](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/refman/lp_format.html#format:LP). This is very close to the mathematical formulation. See [here for more information on file formats](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/refman/model_file_formats.html).

Comment: I am not building a new model. I am trying to solve a model that is published in a paper by Gurobi/python and I am just a novice to Gurobi. 

However, your comment drew my attention to a very important thing so thanks a lot .